# I cannot telnet www.google.com 80 on my centos, why?

Tags: centos, telnet, resolv.conf, resolve

On my centos I have a problem.

I cannot:

```
[root@server]# telnet www.google.com 80
telnet: www.google.com: Name or service not known
www.google.com: Unknown server error
[root@server]#
```

However I can dig google.com

```
[root@server]# dig www.google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.3 <<>> www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 42872
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 180.188.196.76#53(180.188.196.76)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 15 20:15:21 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32

[root@server] #
```

My resolv.conf is

```
# Automatically generated by OnApp (2.3.2)
domain com
nameserver 180.188.196.76
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: You put `resolv.conf` in your tags. Now take a look at it.

Comment: QUERY, status: REFUSED: no, your dig does not work, check nameservers in resolv.conf

Answer (score 1):

Test other domain server (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 for example):

```
dig @8.8.4.4 www.google.com
```

If it could resolve the name, put it in the first place in your /etc/resolv.conf file, then try again the connection against port 80

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

If this is still not working, then the problem is in your internet connection or network configuration, not in the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

At first, it looks like server is refusing your requests:

```
status: REFUSED
```

But, if we take closer look, 0 (zero) msec is a very short time (if server isn't in your local network).

```
Query time: 0 msec

;; SERVER: 180.188.196.76#53(180.188.196.76)
```

Very hard to say what is the problem...

Do you use some local caching for DNS?

- Use your local or ISP's DNS, avoid using worldwide-free DNS servers - you might get some problems accessing CDN files.
- Run BIND